# ImageMagick - Make a color semi-transparent

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to overlay image1 over image2. I want to make a color in image1 semi-transparent. So far I have only been able to overlay image1 over image2 using

```
composite -gravity north image2.png image1.png image3.png
```

How do I make a color (grey in this case) in image1 semi-transparent before overlaying it over image2?

I am using:

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-23 Q16 x86_64 2019-01-09
```

Thnx

Comment: With ImageMagick 7, use magick rather than convert and use magick composite, magick identify, magick montage, etc rather than just composite, identify and montage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make an overlay (image2.png) first, with 3 progressively lighter shades of grey starting with 80/255 on the left, 128/255 in the middle and 200/255 on the right:

```
convert -size 200x438 xc:"gray(80,80,80)" xc:gray xc:"gray(200,200,200)" +append image2.png
```

[image]

Assuming our starting image is this:

[image]

We can now make precisely mid-grey into semi-transparent mid-grey and overlay like this:

```
convert bean.jpg \( image2.png -fill "rgba(128,128,128,0.5)" -opaque gray \) -composite result.png
```

[image]

Or, if we want to also affect the grey(80), we can incorporate some fuzz:

```
convert bean.jpg \( image2.png -fill "rgba(128,128,128,0.5)" -fuzz 20% -opaque gray \) -composite result.png
```

[image]

---

Note that at Version 7 of **ImageMagick**, the commands changed:

```
Version 6       | Version 7
=================================
identify        | magick identify
convert         | magick
mogrify         | magick mogrify
composite       | magick composite
montage         | magick montage
compare         | magick compare
animate         | magick animate
stream          | magick stream
```

The order of parameters is also stricter, favouring:

```
magick [settings] INPUT [settings] [operators] OUTPUT
```

over:

```
convert [settings] [operators] INPUT [settings] [operators] OUTPUT
```

What I mean is that you are expected to load an image prior to applying operators to it, rather than to build up a list of operators and then load an image and hope **ImageMagick** remembers what you said you wanted done if you ever loaded anything.

Comment: Mark, he is using ImageMagick 7. So you might change your commands to replace convert with magick or make a note in your command about the difference.

Comment: Because the overlay image was noisy (too many random pixels with colors close to and including the gray color I was trying to make semi-transparent), I ended up creating a clean version of the overlay image using a sketch template I found (with the gray transparency level pre-set) (template not perfect, but I can tweak to suit). This meant I could use the 'composite' call (or 'convert`) from my question to get the result I needed. I learned this in the process of following your pointers. If my original overlay image was cleaner, I would have used this method. Thanks Mr. Bean ... very helpful!

Comment: To follow-up, if overlay already has a semi-transparent color (gray in my case), a command to overlay is just a standard overlay command such as `composite original.png overlay.png result.png` or `convert original.png overlay.png -composite result.png` (using old school syntax)

Comment: FYI: here's how I ended up using ImageMagick to overlay a semi-transparent image onto another image (among other calls to ImageMagick): https://github.com/mmcc007/screenshots/blob/master/lib/image_magick.dart#L11. Could probably merge some of these multiple calls to ImageMagick into one call as a performance optimization (for the future)